# how to get other elements of an array from associated array when I have a unique value of an array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 61
            [title] => werwer
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 63
            [title] => test
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 88
            [title] => test 2
        )
)
```

How can I get title which has `id=63` in above type of array without looping.

Comment: `$array[1][63]` - try this. And read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: If you realy just want to answer his example (and only this exact array structure) it would still be $array[1]['title']. Your example would access an index that isn't set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can't do that without looping. That doesn't mean you have to use *loop* (foreach/while e t.c.) - but using array functions you will internally iterate array in any case.

For example, in PHP 5.5 that is:

```
$array = [
['id'=>63, 'title'=>'foo'],
['id'=>65, 'title'=>'bar']
];
//use this - if there are more than 2 connected to `id` fields:
$ids    = array_flip(array_column($array, 'id'));//here is iteration, gathering id column
$result = $array[$ids[63]]['title'];
//or else, if `title` is always the only field:
$result = array_column($array, 'title', 'id')[63];
//var_dump($result);
```

-and so on. `array_search()` with `array_walk()` (or similar ways) will hide iteration from you, but it will be done in any case.

Comment: thanks, it can be done in ease with 
`$ids  = array_column($records, 'title', 'id');
echo $result = $ids[63];`

but i don't have PHP 5.5

Comment: You can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784897/how-can-i-get-the-array-of-a-single-type-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-without/18784941#18784941) for earlier versions

Answer (score 0):

Well You can try some crazy stuff like this

```
array_search(61,
    array_combine(
            array_map(function ($a) {
                return $a['title'];
            }, $arr),
            array_map(function ($a) {
                return $a['id'];
            }, $arr)));
```

but it's highly uneffective (there are 4 loops 'hidden' in 2 array_map, array_combine, and array_search). I advise to use looping - just like @JustAPirate wrote.

```
$arr = array(array('id' => 61, 'title' => 'werwer'),
        array('id' => 62, 'title' => 'asdasd'),
        array('id' => 63, 'title' => 'qweqwe'),);

function f($arr, $id) {
    foreach ($arr as $a) {
        if ($a['id'] == $id)
            return $a['title'];
    }
}

var_dump(f($arr, 61));
```

Answer (score -1):

No way to get it without a loop if you don't already know the index of the id 63 in the array.

```
foreach($array as $element) {
    if($element['id'] == 63) {
        echo $element['title'];
    }
}
```

You could change the structure of the array:

```
$array = array(61 => 'werwer', 63 => 'test', 88 => 'test 2');
```

That would result in:

```
Array
(
    [61] => 'werwer'
    [63] => 'test'
    [88] => 'test 2'
)
```

Then you could access/get it with $array[63]